# Using round within class function in python doesn't round at all

Tags: python, function, rounding

I am doing a temperature conversion and want to round conversions to specified decimal length. The program executes with no errors but the conversion ends up being not rounded.

```
def to(self, unit, dp=None):  # convert self.celcius to temperature measure
    if unit == 'C':
        self.number = self.celcius()
    elif unit == 'F':
        self.number = (9 / 5 * self.celcius()) + 32
    elif unit == 'K':
        self.number = self.celcius() + 273.15
    else:
        raise Exception("Unit not recognised")
    if dp: number = round(self.number, dp)
    return f"{self.number}{unit}"

temp_1 = Temperature(32, 'C')
temp_2 = Temperature(100, 'F')
temp_3 = Temperature(324, 'K')

# Convert them
print(temp_1.to('F')) 
print(temp_2.to('K', 3)) 
print(temp_3.to('C', 1))
```

I can provide furher code if needed by the issue seems to be with `if dp: number = round(self.number, dp)`as decimals are not being shortened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if dp:
  number = round(self.number, dp)
```

Here, we're making a new local variable called `number` and then never using it again. You probably meant to set `self.number`.

```
if dp:
  self.number = round(self.number, dp)
```